# Laravel 4 error execution error

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am working on Laravel 4, till yesterday the project was running properly and today all pages showing this error. I ran `composer update`.
I am confused if this is a Laravel 4.1 error, can any one suggest me the solution.

```
Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $config ]].

vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php
```

Comment: did you follow the 4.1 upgrade guide? https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/develop/upgrade.md

Comment: yeah i got it actually the error because of the package i had installed....thank you for reply. Can you suggest me the solution for this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20297064/accessing-class-from-the-package

Comment: try to run composer dump-autoload